Avatar SDK Integration
Do you know any SDKs that can be used as avatars and able to read dynamic text. It’s also better for the avatar to be customizable. i want to integrate it into my mobile & web applications.
Mobile app developed using react & website using mvc, js, $ Jquery with .NET Core as BE
Provide me with free & paid SDKs
